# AngularJS update ng-init on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way in which ng-init will get updated when tableCells will change ? I want to use this approach (or similar) so angular won't have to call findCellsByDate two times.

I also tried to change ng-init with ng-bind or ng-model, but bind will show [object Object] and model will throw an error as there isn't an attribution.

```
<span ng-init='cells = findCellsByDate(tableCells, day)'>
    <div class='text' ng-show='forecastAndActualForCellsAreNotEmpty(cells)'>
        <span ng-bind='getTotalHoursPercentageForCells(cells)'></span>
        <span>%</span>
    </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ng-init works that way, so what I'm thinking is that you should change some of your controller/model code to hold a boolean for `forecastAndActualForCellsAreNotEmpty` which would get updated.

On the other hand you could do it by css. I assume that if `forecastAndActualForCellsAreNotEmpty` returns `false`, `getTotalHoursPercentageForCells` would return 0. So you could bind that to a data attribute and using a css rule make the div go away. But in order to not use `ng-init` you would have to take the content also with css. And the only way to do that, that I know of, is with `:before` and `:after`.
Something like

```
    <div class='text' data-percentage='{{getTotalHoursPercentageForCells(findCellsByDate(tableCells, day))}}'>
    </div>
```

And the css

```css
div[data-percentage=0]{
    display: none;
}

div[data-percentage]:before{
    content: attr(data-percentage) "%";
    display: block;
}
```

Now I wouldn't use `:before` or `:after` to display actual application content, but rather things that are related to style. So I suppose the final recommendation would be to alter the model instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the logic that changes the `cells` variable inside a watch function that observe changes in `tableCells variable`

```
$scope.$watch('tableCells', function(tableCells) {
    if(!tableCells) return;

    $scope.cells = findCellsByDate(tableCells, $scope.day);        
});
```

In this way you keep that logic in the controller

Comment: The 'cells = find...' is used in more parts of the view, so I can't set up watches for them in particular.